# Swagger integration(RestEasy 3.x + WildFly) - 404 Could not find resource

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, wildfly, swagger, resteasy

I'm trying to include Swagger into my project.
I'm using WildFly (10) server with RestEasy 3.0.11, my resources are EJB-powered and the whole project is building with Ant.

Swagger dependencies are provided by WildFly modules.

The problem is when I'm trying to get swagger.json (via *http://localhost:8080/app/api/swagger.json* but I've tried other variants of it as well) I've got a 404 response/blank page in the browser and following console output:

```
09:40:49,893 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (Log4jLogger.java:135) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/app/api/swagger.json
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The *web.xml* configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app>

    <display-name>app</display-name>
    <description>app</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.example.app.examples.web.SwaggerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
</web-app>
```

And here's a SwaggerServlet mentioned above:

```
import io.swagger.config.ScannerFactory;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsScanner;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.SwaggerContextService;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class SwaggerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SwaggerServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            super.init(config);

            BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
            beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
            beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
            beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
            beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
            beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources,io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,my.example.app.exampleresources");
            beanConfig.setScan(true);
            log.info("Swagger servlet has been initialized");
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }

    }
}
```

And while starting my application the servlet seems to initialize:

```
09:40:33,809 INFO  [my.example.app.examples.web.SwaggerServlet] (SwaggerServlet.java:40) Swagger servlet has been initialized
```

My web resource is working and responding properly (on *http://localhost:8080/app/example/listOfExampleResources.json*). The ExampleModel class is just a POJO:

```
@Api(value = "/app")

@Stateless
@Path("/app")
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public class ExampleController {

    @GET
    @Path("/example/listOfExampleResources.json")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get list of example resources", 
        notes = "Note test", 
        response = ExampleModel.class,
        responseContainer = "list"
    )
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<ExampleModel> getList() {
        List<ExampleModel> list = new ArrayList<ExampleModel>();
        ExampleModel example = new ExampleModel();
        example.setName("Hello");
        list.add(example);
        return list;
    }
}
```

I've tried other parameters and configuration approaches such as configuration via custom Application class, defining servlet inside web.xml, manual resources providing.
I was replacing RestEasy with older version (3.0.4) as well - but all in all I'm still getting 404.

Do you have any idea how can I get *swagger.json* resource?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I struggled for a while with this too and failed to get it working in a way that I was happy with. I think I possibly had some luck when defining the list in application, but that would be a real pain going forward

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears to be a well-known issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1669